# Can I get it to automatically send an SMS when covereage is restored?

Tags: sms

On my old Android phone if I tried to send a text message when I was somewhere without coverage it would then automatically send the message when I returned to somewhere with coverage. My new Windows Phone simply fails to send it and I have to go in and manually resend.

Is there any way to set it to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Windows Phone 8 doesn't offer this feature. It doesn't retry automatically to send a text message.

I encourage you to [vote for this feature](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2195085-automatic-retry-for-text-messages) on the Windows Phone's uservoice page.